# A person who truely believes they are an angel, but in reality they are not

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, personality

Not sure what else I can add, looking for a word that describes someone who thinks they are a good person towards others but they actually are not. But not hypocrite or anything, just they really believe they are amazing.

kind regards,

Vince.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you mean _metaphorically_ an angel? Because I'm pretty sure no one you could apply this to is in reality a literal angel.

Comment: Describe exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase--generally we want a sample sentence. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done. List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If they truly believe they are behaving well I might use

> Delusional

It's close, but I don't think it matches the narcissism the prompt implies. On that note

> Narcissist

may also work.

Answer (score 0):

*Well-intentioned* is often used for the purpose of expressing something like this, implying that good intentions do not always work out as meant.

Oxford dictionay: `Having or showing good intentions despite a lack of success or fortunate results.`

To strengthen the phrase, since well-intentioned is not yet an angel, you can have ***best-intentioned*** people.

*Well-meaning*, *well-meant* are closely related alternatives, but don't work with *best*, so you'd need an additional word to intensify your meaning.